# Python 3.7 and visdom error：unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, visdom

```
viz = visdom.Visdom(env=DATASET+ ' ' + MODEL)
if not viz.check_connection:
    print("Visdom is not connected. Did you run 'python -m visdom.server' ?")
```

My teacher gave me some codes to run, but I failed.
It said:"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' ". How to solve it? I' m not familiar with Python.
The followings  are my code.

```
    # Python 2/3 compatiblity
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

# Torch
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data
from torchsummary import summary

# Numpy, scipy, scikit-image, spectral
import numpy as np
import sklearn.svm
import sklearn.model_selection
from skimage import io
# Visualization
import seaborn as sns
import visdom

import os
from utils import metrics, convert_to_color_, convert_from_color_,\
    display_dataset, display_predictions, explore_spectrums, plot_spectrums,\
    sample_gt, build_dataset, show_results, compute_imf_weights, get_device
from datasets import get_dataset, HyperX, open_file, DATASETS_CONFIG
from models import get_model, train, test, save_model

import argparse

dataset_names = [v['name'] if 'name' in v.keys() else k for k, v in DATASETS_CONFIG.items()]

# Argument parser for CLI interaction
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run deep learning experiments on"
                                             " various hyperspectral datasets")
parser.add_argument('--dataset', type=str, default=None, choices=dataset_names,
                    help="Dataset to use.")
parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, default=None,
                    help="Model to train. Available:\n"
                    "SVM (linear), "
                    "SVM_grid (grid search on linear, poly and RBF kernels), "
                    "baseline (fully connected NN), "
                    "hu (1D CNN), "
                    "hamida (3D CNN + 1D classifier), "
                    "lee (3D FCN), "
                    "chen (3D CNN), "
                    "li (3D CNN), "
                    "he (3D CNN), "
                    "luo (3D CNN), "
                    "sharma (2D CNN), "
                    "boulch (1D semi-supervised CNN), "
                    "liu (3D semi-supervised CNN), "
                    "mou (1D RNN)")
parser.add_argument('--folder', type=str, help="Folder where to store the "
                    "datasets (defaults to the current working directory).",
                    default="./Datasets/")
parser.add_argument('--cuda', type=int, default=-1,
                    help="Specify CUDA device (defaults to -1, which learns on CPU)")
parser.add_argument('--runs', type=int, default=1, help="Number of runs (default: 1)")
parser.add_argument('--restore', type=str, default=None,
                    help="Weights to use for initialization, e.g. a checkpoint")

# Dataset options
group_dataset = parser.add_argument_group('Dataset')
group_dataset.add_argument('--training_sample', type=float, default=10,
                    help="Percentage of samples to use for training (default: 10%%)")
group_dataset.add_argument('--sampling_mode', type=str, help="Sampling mode"
                    " (random sampling or disjoint, default: random)",
                    default='random')
group_dataset.add_argument('--train_set', type=str, default=None,
                    help="Path to the train ground truth (optional, this "
                    "supersedes the --sampling_mode option)")
group_dataset.add_argument('--test_set', type=str, default=None,
                    help="Path to the test set (optional, by default "
                    "the test_set is the entire ground truth minus the training)")
# Training options
group_train = parser.add_argument_group('Training')
group_train.add_argument('--epoch', type=int, help="Training epochs (optional, if"
                    " absent will be set by the model)")
group_train.add_argument('--patch_size', type=int,
                    help="Size of the spatial neighbourhood (optional, if "
                    "absent will be set by the model)")
group_train.add_argument('--lr', type=float,
                    help="Learning rate, set by the model if not specified.")
group_train.add_argument('--class_balancing', action='store_true',
                    help="Inverse median frequency class balancing (default = False)")
group_train.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int,
                    help="Batch size (optional, if absent will be set by the model")
group_train.add_argument('--test_stride', type=int, default=1,
                     help="Sliding window step stride during inference (default = 1)")
# Data augmentation parameters
group_da = parser.add_argument_group('Data augmentation')
group_da.add_argument('--flip_augmentation', action='store_true',
                    help="Random flips (if patch_size > 1)")
group_da.add_argument('--radiation_augmentation', action='store_true',
                    help="Random radiation noise (illumination)")
group_da.add_argument('--mixture_augmentation', action='store_true',
                    help="Random mixes between spectra")

parser.add_argument('--with_exploration', action='store_true',
                    help="See data exploration visualization")
parser.add_argument('--download', type=str, default=None, nargs='+',
                    choices=dataset_names,
                    help="Download the specified datasets and quits.")



args = parser.parse_args()

CUDA_DEVICE = get_device(args.cuda)

# % of training samples
SAMPLE_PERCENTAGE = args.training_sample
# Data augmentation ?
FLIP_AUGMENTATION = args.flip_augmentation
RADIATION_AUGMENTATION = args.radiation_augmentation
MIXTURE_AUGMENTATION = args.mixture_augmentation
# Dataset name
DATASET = args.dataset
# Model name
MODEL = args.model
# Number of runs (for cross-validation)
N_RUNS = args.runs
# Spatial context size (number of neighbours in each spatial direction)
PATCH_SIZE = args.patch_size
# Add some visualization of the spectra ?
DATAVIZ = args.with_exploration
# Target folder to store/download/load the datasets
FOLDER = args.folder
# Number of epochs to run
EPOCH = args.epoch
# Sampling mode, e.g random sampling
SAMPLING_MODE = args.sampling_mode
# Pre-computed weights to restore
CHECKPOINT = args.restore
# Learning rate for the SGD
LEARNING_RATE = args.lr
# Automated class balancing
CLASS_BALANCING = args.class_balancing
# Training ground truth file
TRAIN_GT = args.train_set
# Testing ground truth file
TEST_GT = args.test_set
TEST_STRIDE = args.test_stride

if args.download is not None and len(args.download) > 0:
    for dataset in args.download:
        get_dataset(dataset, target_folder=FOLDER)
    quit()

viz = visdom.Visdom(env=DATASET+ ' ' + MODEL)
if not viz.check_connection:
    print("Visdom is not connected. Did you run 'python -m visdom.server' ?")


hyperparams = vars(args)
# Load the dataset
img, gt, LABEL_VALUES, IGNORED_LABELS, RGB_BANDS, palette = get_dataset(DATASET,
                                                               FOLDER)
# Number of classes
N_CLASSES = len(LABEL_VALUES)
# Number of bands (last dimension of the image tensor)
N_BANDS = img.shape[-1]

# Parameters for the SVM grid search
SVM_GRID_PARAMS = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3],
                                       'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                   {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                   {'kernel': ['poly'], 'degree': [3], 'gamma': [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3]}]

if palette is None:
    # Generate color palette
    palette = {0: (0, 0, 0)}
    for k, color in enumerate(sns.color_palette("hls", len(LABEL_VALUES) - 1)):
        palette[k + 1] = tuple(np.asarray(255 * np.array(color), dtype='uint8'))
invert_palette = {v: k for k, v in palette.items()}

def convert_to_color(x):
    return convert_to_color_(x, palette=palette)
def convert_from_color(x):
    return convert_from_color_(x, palette=invert_palette)


# Instantiate the experiment based on predefined networks
hyperparams.update({'n_classes': N_CLASSES, 'n_bands': N_BANDS, 'ignored_labels': IGNORED_LABELS, 'device': CUDA_DEVICE})
hyperparams = dict((k, v) for k, v in hyperparams.items() if v is not None)

# Show the image and the ground truth
display_dataset(img, gt, RGB_BANDS, LABEL_VALUES, palette, viz)
color_gt = convert_to_color(gt)

if DATAVIZ:
    # Data exploration : compute and show the mean spectrums
    mean_spectrums = explore_spectrums(img, gt, LABEL_VALUES, viz,
                                       ignored_labels=IGNORED_LABELS)
    plot_spectrums(mean_spectrums, viz, title='Mean spectrum/class')

results = []
# run the experiment several times
for run in range(N_RUNS):
    if TRAIN_GT is not None and TEST_GT is not None:
        train_gt = open_file(TRAIN_GT)
        test_gt = open_file(TEST_GT)
    elif TRAIN_GT is not None:
        train_gt = open_file(TRAIN_GT)
        test_gt = np.copy(gt)
        w, h = test_gt.shape
        test_gt[(train_gt > 0)[:w,:h]] = 0
    elif TEST_GT is not None:
        test_gt = open_file(TEST_GT)
    else:
    # Sample random training spectra
        train_gt, test_gt = sample_gt(gt, SAMPLE_PERCENTAGE, mode=SAMPLING_MODE)
    print("{} samples selected (over {})".format(np.count_nonzero(train_gt),
                                                 np.count_nonzero(gt)))
    print("Running an experiment with the {} model".format(MODEL),
          "run {}/{}".format(run + 1, N_RUNS))

    display_predictions(convert_to_color(train_gt), viz, caption="Train ground truth")
    display_predictions(convert_to_color(test_gt), viz, caption="Test ground truth")

    if MODEL == 'SVM_grid':
        print("Running a grid search SVM")
        # Grid search SVM (linear and RBF)
        X_train, y_train = build_dataset(img, train_gt,
                                         ignored_labels=IGNORED_LABELS)
        class_weight = 'balanced' if CLASS_BALANCING else None
        clf = sklearn.svm.SVC(class_weight=class_weight)
        clf = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, SVM_GRID_PARAMS, verbose=5, n_jobs=4)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print("SVM best parameters : {}".format(clf.best_params_))
        prediction = clf.predict(img.reshape(-1, N_BANDS))
        save_model(clf, MODEL, DATASET)
        prediction = prediction.reshape(img.shape[:2])
    elif MODEL == 'SVM':
        X_train, y_train = build_dataset(img, train_gt,
                                         ignored_labels=IGNORED_LABELS)
        class_weight = 'balanced' if CLASS_BALANCING else None
        clf = sklearn.svm.SVC(class_weight=class_weight)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        save_model(clf, MODEL, DATASET)
        prediction = clf.predict(img.reshape(-1, N_BANDS))
        prediction = prediction.reshape(img.shape[:2])
    elif MODEL == 'SGD':
        X_train, y_train = build_dataset(img, train_gt,
                                         ignored_labels=IGNORED_LABELS)
        X_train, y_train = sklearn.utils.shuffle(X_train, y_train)
        scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
        X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        class_weight = 'balanced' if CLASS_BALANCING else None
        clf = sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(class_weight=class_weight, learning_rate='optimal', tol=1e-3, average=10)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        save_model(clf, MODEL, DATASET)
        prediction = clf.predict(scaler.transform(img.reshape(-1, N_BANDS)))
        prediction = prediction.reshape(img.shape[:2])
    elif MODEL == 'nearest':
        X_train, y_train = build_dataset(img, train_gt,
                                         ignored_labels=IGNORED_LABELS)
        X_train, y_train = sklearn.utils.shuffle(X_train, y_train)
        class_weight = 'balanced' if CLASS_BALANCING else None
        clf = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(weights='distance')
        clf = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(clf, {'n_neighbors': [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]}, verbose=5, n_jobs=4)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        save_model(clf, MODEL, DATASET)
        prediction = clf.predict(img.reshape(-1, N_BANDS))
        prediction = prediction.reshape(img.shape[:2])
    else:
        # Neural network
        model, optimizer, loss, hyperparams = get_model(MODEL, **hyperparams)
        if CLASS_BALANCING:
            weights = compute_imf_weights(train_gt, N_CLASSES, IGNORED_LABELS)
            hyperparams['weights'] = torch.from_numpy(weights)
        # Split train set in train/val
        train_gt, val_gt = sample_gt(train_gt, 0.95, mode='random')
        # Generate the dataset
        train_dataset = HyperX(img, train_gt, **hyperparams)
        train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                       batch_size=hyperparams['batch_size'],
                                       #pin_memory=hyperparams['device'],
                                       shuffle=True)
        val_dataset = HyperX(img, val_gt, **hyperparams)
        val_loader = data.DataLoader(val_dataset,
                                     #pin_memory=hyperparams['device'],
                                     batch_size=hyperparams['batch_size'])

        print(hyperparams)
        print("Network :")
        with torch.no_grad():
            for input, _ in train_loader:
                break
            summary(model.to(hyperparams['device']), input.size()[1:])
            # We would like to use device=hyperparams['device'] altough we have
            # to wait for torchsummary to be fixed first.

        if CHECKPOINT is not None:
            model.load_state_dict(torch.load(CHECKPOINT))

        try:
            train(model, optimizer, loss, train_loader, hyperparams['epoch'],
                  scheduler=hyperparams['scheduler'], device=hyperparams['device'],
                  supervision=hyperparams['supervision'], val_loader=val_loader,
                  display=viz)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Allow the user to stop the training
            pass

        probabilities = test(model, img, hyperparams)
        prediction = np.argmax(probabilities, axis=-1)

    run_results = metrics(prediction, test_gt, ignored_labels=hyperparams['ignored_labels'], n_classes=N_CLASSES)

    mask = np.zeros(gt.shape, dtype='bool')
    for l in IGNORED_LABELS:
        mask[gt == l] = True
    prediction[mask] = 0

    color_prediction = convert_to_color(prediction)
    display_predictions(color_prediction, viz, gt=convert_to_color(test_gt), caption="Prediction vs. test ground truth")

    results.append(run_results)
    show_results(run_results, viz, label_values=LABEL_VALUES)

if N_RUNS > 1:
    show_results(results, viz, label_values=LABEL_VALUES, agregated=True)
```

The following is dataset.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This file contains the PyTorch dataset for hyperspectral images and
related helpers.
"""
import spectral
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.utils
import torch.utils.data
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urllib import urlretrieve

from utils import open_file

DATASETS_CONFIG = {
        'PaviaC': {
            'urls': ['http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/e/e3/Pavia.mat', 
                     'http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/5/53/Pavia_gt.mat'],
            'img': 'Pavia.mat',
            'gt': 'Pavia_gt.mat'
            },
        'Salinas': {
            'urls': ['http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/a/a3/Salinas_corrected.mat',
                     'http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/f/fa/Salinas_gt.mat'],
            'img': 'Salinas_corrected.mat',
            'gt': 'Salinas_gt.mat'
            },
        'PaviaU': {
            'urls': ['http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/e/ee/PaviaU.mat',
                     'http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/5/50/PaviaU_gt.mat'],
            'img': 'PaviaU.mat',
            'gt': 'PaviaU_gt.mat'
            },
        'KSC': {
            'urls': ['http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/2/26/KSC.mat',
                     'http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/a/a6/KSC_gt.mat'],
            'img': 'KSC.mat',
            'gt': 'KSC_gt.mat'
            },
        'IndianPines': {
            'urls': ['http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/6/67/Indian_pines_corrected.mat',
                     'http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/c/c4/Indian_pines_gt.mat'],
            'img': 'Indian_pines_corrected.mat',
            'gt': 'Indian_pines_gt.mat'
            },
        'Botswana': {
            'urls': ['http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/7/72/Botswana.mat',
                     'http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/uploads/5/58/Botswana_gt.mat'],
            'img': 'Botswana.mat',
            'gt': 'Botswana_gt.mat',
            }
    }

try:
    from custom_datasets import CUSTOM_DATASETS_CONFIG
    DATASETS_CONFIG.update(CUSTOM_DATASETS_CONFIG)
except ImportError:
    pass

class TqdmUpTo(tqdm):
    """Provides `update_to(n)` which uses `tqdm.update(delta_n)`."""
    def update_to(self, b=1, bsize=1, tsize=None):
        """
        b  : int, optional
            Number of blocks transferred so far [default: 1].
        bsize  : int, optional
            Size of each block (in tqdm units) [default: 1].
        tsize  : int, optional
            Total size (in tqdm units). If [default: None] remains unchanged.
        """
        if tsize is not None:
            self.total = tsize
        self.update(b * bsize - self.n)  # will also set self.n = b * bsize


def get_dataset(dataset_name, target_folder="./", datasets=DATASETS_CONFIG):
    """ Gets the dataset specified by name and return the related components.
    Args:
        dataset_name: string with the name of the dataset
        target_folder (optional): folder to store the datasets, defaults to ./
        datasets (optional): dataset configuration dictionary, defaults to prebuilt one
    Returns:
        img: 3D hyperspectral image (WxHxB)
        gt: 2D int array of labels
        label_values: list of class names
        ignored_labels: list of int classes to ignore
        rgb_bands: int tuple that correspond to red, green and blue bands
    """
    palette = None

    if dataset_name not in datasets.keys():
        raise ValueError("{} dataset is unknown.".format(dataset_name))

    dataset = datasets[dataset_name]

    folder = target_folder + datasets[dataset_name].get('folder', dataset_name + '/')
    if dataset.get('download', True):
        # Download the dataset if is not present
        if not os.path.isdir(folder):
            os.mkdir(folder)
        for url in datasets[dataset_name]['urls']:
            # download the files
            filename = url.split('/')[-1]
            if not os.path.exists(folder + filename):
                with TqdmUpTo(unit='B', unit_scale=True, miniters=1,
                          desc="Downloading {}".format(filename)) as t:
                    urlretrieve(url, filename=folder + filename,
                                     reporthook=t.update_to)
    elif not os.path.isdir(folder):
       print("WARNING: {} is not downloadable.".format(dataset_name))

    if dataset_name == 'PaviaC':
        # Load the image
        img = open_file(folder + 'Pavia.mat')['pavia']

        rgb_bands = (55, 41, 12)

        gt = open_file(folder + 'Pavia_gt.mat')['pavia_gt']

        label_values = ["Undefined", "Water", "Trees", "Asphalt",
                        "Self-Blocking Bricks", "Bitumen", "Tiles", "Shadows",
                        "Meadows", "Bare Soil"]

        ignored_labels = [0]

    elif dataset_name == 'PaviaU':
        # Load the image
        img = open_file(folder + 'PaviaU.mat')['paviaU']

        rgb_bands = (55, 41, 12)

        gt = open_file(folder + 'PaviaU_gt.mat')['paviaU_gt']

        label_values = ['Undefined', 'Asphalt', 'Meadows', 'Gravel', 'Trees',
                        'Painted metal sheets', 'Bare Soil', 'Bitumen',
                        'Self-Blocking Bricks', 'Shadows']

        ignored_labels = [0]


    elif dataset_name == 'Salinas':
        img = open_file(folder + 'Salinas.mat')['Salinas_corrected']

        rgb_bands = (43, 21, 11)  # AVIRIS sensor

        gt = open_file(folder + 'Salinas_gt.mat')['Salinas_gt']

        label_values = ['Undefined','Brocoli_green_weeds_1', 'Brocoli_green_weeds_2','Fallow','Fallow_rough_plow','Fallow_smooth','Stubble','Celery',
                       'Grapes_untrained','Soil_vinyard_develop','Corn_senesced_green_weeds','Lettuce_romaine_4wk','Lettuce_romaine_5wk','Lettuce_romaine_6wk',
                       'Lettuce_romaine_7wk','Vinyard_untrained','Vinyard_vertical_trellis']

        ignored_labels = [0]    

    elif dataset_name == 'IndianPines':
        # Load the image
        img = open_file(folder + 'Indian_pines_corrected.mat')
        img = img['indian_pines_corrected']

        rgb_bands = (43, 21, 11)  # AVIRIS sensor

        gt = open_file(folder + 'Indian_pines_gt.mat')['indian_pines_gt']
        label_values = ["Undefined", "Alfalfa", "Corn-notill", "Corn-mintill",
                        "Corn", "Grass-pasture", "Grass-trees",
                        "Grass-pasture-mowed", "Hay-windrowed", "Oats",
                        "Soybean-notill", "Soybean-mintill", "Soybean-clean",
                        "Wheat", "Woods", "Buildings-Grass-Trees-Drives",
                        "Stone-Steel-Towers"]

        ignored_labels = [0]

    elif dataset_name == 'Botswana':
        # Load the image
        img = open_file(folder + 'Botswana.mat')['Botswana']

        rgb_bands = (75, 33, 15)

        gt = open_file(folder + 'Botswana_gt.mat')['Botswana_gt']
        label_values = ["Undefined", "Water", "Hippo grass",
                        "Floodplain grasses 1", "Floodplain grasses 2",
                        "Reeds", "Riparian", "Firescar", "Island interior",
                        "Acacia woodlands", "Acacia shrublands",
                        "Acacia grasslands", "Short mopane", "Mixed mopane",
                        "Exposed soils"]

        ignored_labels = [0]

    elif dataset_name == 'KSC':
        # Load the image
        img = open_file(folder + 'KSC.mat')['KSC']

        rgb_bands = (43, 21, 11)  # AVIRIS sensor

        gt = open_file(folder + 'KSC_gt.mat')['KSC_gt']
        label_values = ["Undefined", "Scrub", "Willow swamp",
                        "Cabbage palm hammock", "Cabbage palm/oak hammock",
                        "Slash pine", "Oak/broadleaf hammock",
                        "Hardwood swamp", "Graminoid marsh", "Spartina marsh",
                        "Cattail marsh", "Salt marsh", "Mud flats", "Wate"]

        ignored_labels = [0]
    else:
        # Custom dataset
        img, gt, rgb_bands, ignored_labels, label_values, palette = CUSTOM_DATASETS_CONFIG[dataset_name]['loader'](folder)

    # Filter NaN out
    nan_mask = np.isnan(img.sum(axis=-1))
    if np.count_nonzero(nan_mask) > 0:
       print("Warning: NaN have been found in the data. It is preferable to remove them beforehand. Learning on NaN data is disabled.")
    img[nan_mask] = 0
    gt[nan_mask] = 0
    ignored_labels.append(0)

    ignored_labels = list(set(ignored_labels))
    # Normalization
    img = np.asarray(img, dtype='float32')
    img = (img - np.min(img)) / (np.max(img) - np.min(img))
    return img, gt, label_values, ignored_labels, rgb_bands, palette
```

Comment: what are `DATASET` and `MODEL`?

Comment: DATASET is a varible of  data's name, and MODEL is a varible of model's name. There is a little more code. Could you give me your email address?  So I can show you my code in detail. Thank you!

Comment: No I cant. Why cant you include the all the code in your original post?

Comment: Sorry, I have included my code in the post. Could you help me?

Comment: how do you run the program? Is it from the command line? If so what do you type?

Comment: I write the code to the .py file and run the program in the PyCharm. However, unfortunately, it show that TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'.

Comment: I suspect that you have to pass `DATASET` & `MODEL` as arguments to the program when you run it. I dont know how you do that in PyCharm but a quick Google search should show you how.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will try

Comment: I made it! It runs well in the cmd. Thanks a lot.